# How to use different row layouts in Android listiview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have two layouts for listview.(one for separator, another one for list item) 
And I have two view holder classes for each layouts. How to use these different layouts properly in listview?

Below is my `getView()` method of custom adapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    int pos = position;
    final Context context = parent.getContext();
    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(position);
    View view = convertView;

    switch(viewType){

        case TYPE_ITEM:
            HolderItem holder_item;

            if(view == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                holder_item = new HolderItem();
                holder_item.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                holder_item.subTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_title);
                view.setTag(holder_item);
            }else{
                holder_item = (HolderItem) view.getTag();
            }

            holder_item.title.setText(titleList.get(pos));
            holder_item.subTitle.setText(infoList.get(pos));
            return view;

        case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
            HolderSeparator holder_sep;

            if(view == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, parent, false);

                holder_sep = new HolderSeparator();
                holder_sep.separator = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_header);
                view.setTag(holder_sep);
            }else{
                holder_sep = (HolderSeparator)view.getTag();
            }

            holder_sep.separator.setText(titleList.get(pos));
            return view;


        default:
            return view;
    }

}

public int getItemViewType(int position){
    if(position == 0 || position == 5) return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    else return TYPE_ITEM;
}

class HolderItem{
    TextView title;
    TextView subTitle;
}
class HolderSeparator{
    TextView separator;
}
```

There are two separators(in the top of listview and the middle of listview)
Above code works fine first but when I starts to scroll it occurs `ClassCastException`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.soonoo.listtest.Adapter$Holder cannot be cast to com.soonoo.listtest.Adapter$HolderItem
```

I think my code uses two view holders and when scrolls, new list item uses view holder of separator. How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your `getViewTypeCount()` method?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know it is necessary. I overrided it and works find. Tnank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override `getItemViewType()`, you also need to override `getViewTypeCount()`, to indicate how many different row types you have.